# Use of undeclared identifier 'NSBundle'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsbundle

This is how my file.mm looks like:

```
const char *readFromFileMac(const char *fileName) {
    fileName =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @(fileName)].UTF8String;
    return fileName;
}
```

Xcode gives me the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'NSBundle'`. Do I need to include some framework or header file to be able to use the `NSBundle` name?

The only thing I have done is to copy my project to an other directory. After the copy I got this error, its was working before. I am using Xcode 8.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

Remember to add the `Foundation.framework` to your linked libraries/frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Your project Setting > Build Phases > Frameworks > Search For (Foundation) and add it. once done. go to your.h file and place is below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```